# Clojure: Should I prepend new- or make- to constructor functions?

Tags: clojure

When creating a new Java object via a wrapper function, what is the "constructor" naming standard?  Should I prepend `make-` or `new-` to the function name?  Or just call it the type of thing it returns?  At one point I got accustomed to using `make-` because it's the way it was done in the Scheme book SICP.

For example, I'm passing some stuff to a function which eventually returns an instance of a Java class.  Here are a few examples:

```
(def myimage1 (make-image "img.svg" 100 200))  ; These all return
(def myimage2 (new-image "img.svg" 100 200))   ; an instance of
(def myimage3 (image "img.svg" 100 200))       ; javafx.scene.image.Image
```

Is it the same for creating Clojure-only structs, such as maps, etc?:

```
(def mystruct1 (make-custom-struct args))
(def mystruct2 (new-custom-struct args))
(def mystruct3 (custom-struct args))
```

I prefer the last version without `make-` or `new-`, but often times the binding (for example inside a `let`) would have the same name, which would suggest prepending the constructor name, or using a different binding name, such as:

```
(let [image (make-image "img.svg" 100 200)] ...)
(let [imuj (image "img.svg" 100 200)] ...)
```

However other times I'd just like to use the function in-line without the cluttering of the `new-` or `make-':

```
(do-something-with-an-image (image "img.svg" 100 200))
```

Comment: As a non-native english speaker, please don't name anything `imuj`, I had to pause for a while until I "said it out loud" in my head in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuart Sierra [suggests](http://stuartsierra.com/2016/01/09/how-to-name-clojure-functions) not using a prefix. His idea is that a pure function can be replaced with its implementation, and so a simple noun makes a better name in that sense than a verb.

Comment: while I agree that `(image ..` is the way to go here, could you extend you answer to be a little bit more than tiny fact.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `(image ...)` is the version that looks the best. However, you are right that you can easily end up shadowing the function with local variables. What can you do?

- Namespaces are here to counter the issue introduced by the Lisp-1 nature of Clojure:

  ```
  (let [image (png/image "file.png")] ...)
  ```
- Alternatively, when you are in the same namespace, you should give better variable names: `image` is a little bit generic; try something more precise, like `avatar` or `thumbnail`. Note also that sometimes `image` *is* the best name to give to the variable.
- You can also prefix or suffix variable names, like `user-image`, `old-image` or `new-image`.
- Regarding functions, the `make-` prefix is not bad: it is readable, unambiguous and it fixes the problem of shadowing existing bindings. So don't discard it too quickly. This prefix tends to be found more often than `new-`, which is a little unclear: sometimes you have *old* and *new* data, where *new* is an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

I think `->` is a fun prefix, and it's already used by the factory functions generated by `defrecord`.

Comment: if you use this for things other than records be sure to carefully document the fact that the returned thing is not as expected.